# Invalid Path Format : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, path

Can anyone help me with the path format in C#?
Im using sharepoint folder path and it seems incorrect path format..

Here is my path :

**`https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Investor/Department Folder/COB/COB/PRS/PRS DIGITAL BOOKING`**

Comment: How are you trying to use this path?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to move a file from a folder to a folder (the path above), so what I did is FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(OutputPath,filename));

Comment: I see! Well, unfortunately, the `File` apis are unable to interact with `URI` paths. You're going to want to get the _physical_ path of the file, if it's local to the machine you are trying to run this code on, or you're going to need to make a web request for the file and then save it locally.

Comment: Yup that's the problem and I already found out the actual path on local.. and the code works perfectly